# How to Load a CSV File from zipped folder from URL into Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, zip

I wanted to load a CSV file from a zipped folder from a URL into a Pandas DataFrame. I referred [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41218216/using-pandas-to-download-load-zipped-csv-file-from-url) and used the same solution as follows:

```
from urllib import request
import zipfile

# link to the zip file
link = 'https://cricsheet.org/downloads/'
# the zip file is named as ipl_csv2.zip
request.urlretrieve(link, 'ipl_csv2.zip')
compressed_file = zipfile.ZipFile('ipl_csv2.zip')

# I need the csv file named all_matches.csv from ipl_csv2.zip
csv_file = compressed_file.open('all_matches.csv')
data = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
data.head()
```

But after running the code, I'm getting an error as:

```
BadZipFile                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-7b7a01259813> in <module>
      1 link = 'https://cricsheet.org/downloads/'
      2 request.urlretrieve(link, 'ipl_csv2.zip')
----> 3 compressed_file = zipfile.ZipFile('ipl_csv2.zip')
      4 csv_file = compressed_file.open('all_matches.csv')
      5 data = pd.read_csv(csv_file)

~\Anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py in __init__(self, file, mode, compression, allowZip64, compresslevel, strict_timestamps)
   1267         try:
   1268             if mode == 'r':
-> 1269                 self._RealGetContents()
   1270             elif mode in ('w', 'x'):
   1271                 # set the modified flag so central directory gets written

~\Anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py in _RealGetContents(self)
   1334             raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
   1335         if not endrec:
-> 1336             raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
   1337         if self.debug > 1:
   1338             print(endrec)

BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

I'm not much used to zip file handling in Python. So please help me out here as to what correction do I need to make in my code?

If I open the URL `https://cricsheet.org/downloads/ipl_csv2.zip` in a web browser, the zip file gets automatically downloaded in my system. As data gets added daily in this zip file, I want to access the URL and directly get the CSV file via Python to save storage.

**Edit1:** If you guys have any other code solution, then please do share...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I did after discussion with @nobleknight below:

```
# importing libraries
import zipfile
from urllib.request import urlopen
import shutil
import os

url = 'https://cricsheet.org/downloads/ipl_csv2.zip'
file_name = 'ipl_csv2.zip'

# extracting zipfile from URL
with urlopen(url) as response, open(file_name, 'wb') as out_file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(response, out_file)

    # extracting required file from zipfile
    with zipfile.ZipFile(file_name) as zf:
        zf.extract('all_matches.csv')

# deleting the zipfile from the directory
os.remove('ipl_csv2.zip')

# loading data from the file
data = pd.read_csv('all_matches.csv')
```

This solution prevents the `ContentTooShortError` and the `HTTPForbiddenError` errors which I have been facing for every solution I find in the net. Thanks to @nobleknight for providing me a part of the solution with reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31706921/14429185).

Any other thoughts are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
link = "https://cricsheet.org/downloads/ipl_csv2.zip"
```

No worry if file gets downloaded, cancel downloading if you don't want that file.
You will always get updated data from `link`.

Comment: Now I'm getting an error as ```ContentTooShortError: <urlopen error retrieval incomplete: got only 879104 out of 3319150 bytes>``` at this line ```request.urlretrieve(link, 'ipl_csv2.zip')```

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31706921/14429185) will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the redirection, but this solution extracts all the files into the system, and I need just one, that too to be read to a Pandas DataFrame. Any way of achieving this?

Comment: try this ```compressed_file.extract("all_matches.csv", "matches")``` and then read ```data = pd.read_csv("matches.csv")```

Comment: Thanks, but I replaced ```zf.extractall()``` with ```zf.extract('all_matches.csv')```, it worked..

Comment: nice! keep going